# HttpHandler fails to handle http requests

Tags: java, server, httphandler, httpserver

I'm trying to build https proxy server using com.sun.net.httpServer.* library.
when I'm defining the server context as follows:

```
httpServer.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
```

and I open from a browser the url: "https://localhost:443/test" it works as expected, but when the server context is defined this way:

```
httpServer.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
```

I notice that my handler is not being used when I enter a URL like: "https://www.google.co.il/"

What am I missing?

Comment: Please don't undo my edits as they make things easier to read.

Comment: You entered `https://www.google.co.il` in a web browser?  Did you configure your browser to use your HTTP proxy server listening on `localhost:443`?

Comment: HTTPS URLs begin with "https://" and use port 443 by default. (taken from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)

Answer (score 0):

This line will only change the context path, not the server URL.

```
httpServer.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
```

So for this context, you will get a response at this URL - "https://localhost:443/".

Comment: Isn't there a way to define the context in a way that every request will trigger the handler ?

Comment: @GilYitzhak Yes we can define the context (in this case /test or /). But you still need to provide the server name (http://localhost) for the client to hit the server.